Just installed node.js on windows and when I went to use 'npm install *insert package here*', I would get an error
On a new machine, I installed node.js v22.0.0 and when I went to install a package, it would hit me with this error:
PS C:\Users\user\Desktop\CC> npm nuxi init nuxt-dojo
node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1205
  throw err;
  ^
Error: Cannot find module 'C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\bin\npm-cli.js'
    at Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1202:15)
    at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1027:27)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:187:14)
    at node:internal/main/run_main_module:28:49 {
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
  requireStack: []
} 

Upon further investigation, this would result in an error with any command starting with npm.

Questions and answers should be separate; SO isn’t a blog

This is a duplicate of NPM: npm-cli.js not found when running npm
